# What is the right way to define constants when there is a huge number of constants?

Tags: java, enums, config, constants, configuration-files

I'm working on some code which has a large number of constants to be defined. It primarily deals with `Marketplace` constants (could be US, UK, INDIA, JAPAN) and associated `MarketplaceMerchantMapping` which basically maps a `MerchantID` with a `MarketplaceID`.

For example:

```
public enum Marketplace {

    US("US"),
    JP("JP"),
    UK("UK"),
    IN("IN"),
    NZ("NZ"),
    CA("CA"),
    FR("FR"),
    ... 
    ...

  // This could go up to some 400 marketplaces

    private final String stringValue;

    public boolean isWest() {
        return this == US || this == CA || this == UK;
    }

    public boolean isEast() {
        return this == IN || this == NZ || this == JP;
    }

}
```

```
public enum MarketplaceMerchantMapping {

    USMAP(MarketplaceID.US, MerchantID.US, Marketplace.US),
    JPMAP(MarketplaceID.JP, MerchantID.JP, Marketplace.JP),
    UKMAP(MarketplaceID.UK, MerchantID.UK, Marketplace.UK),
    NZMAP(MarketplaceID.NZ, MerchantID.NZ, Marketplace.NZ),
    INMAP(MarketplaceID.IN, MerchantID.IN, Marketplace.IN),
    CAMAP(MarketplaceID.CA, MerchantID.CA, Marketplace.CA),
    FRMAP(MarketplaceID.FR, MerchantID.FR, Marketplace.FR),
    ...
    ... 

   // THis can go up to 400 Marketplaces * Number of merchantIds in each marketplace.


}
```

There are other similar constants defined similarly as enums or static constants.

This really is not scalable because every time we add support for a new Marketplace and Merchants, we need to go and update a bunch of files and test them and these config changes themselves take up a lot of developer time.

Ideally, I would like to know if there some way to define these constants in some config file and read those files to create the constants. Is there a way to create such enum constants by reading and parsing some config file?

So that if I have a config file with the following entries:

ConfigFile.cfg:

```
WestMarketplaces = ("US", "AG", "MX", "CA", ...) // Expand this later as required
EastMarketplaces = ("IN", "AU", "SG", "JP", ...) // Expand this later as required
EUMarketplaces = ("UK", "FR", "SP", ...) // Expand this later as required

WestMerchantIds = ("WA", "WB", "WC", "WD", ...) // Expand this later as required
WestMerchantIds = ("EA", "EB", "EC", "WD", ...) // Expand this later as required
EUMerchantIds = ("EUA", "EUB", "EUC", "WDD", ...) // Expand this later as required

marketplaceMerchantMapping = {
  "US" = "WA";
  "CA" = "WB";
  "MX" = "WC";
  "AU" = "EA";
  "IN" = "EB";
  "JP" = "EC";
  "UK" = "EUA";
  "FR" = "EUB";
...
} // Expand this later as required
```

Then, can it read these constants from the config file and build the appropriate enums or static constants?

Is this possible to do?

Comment: *This can go upto 400 Marketplaces * Number of merchantIds*... persist in a data store, what's the harm?

Comment: Enums are used if all values are known at compile time. If you are planning to expand the list later, you should not use enums.

Comment: oh wow! we have close to the same thing, _but very close_ to this. what we have done is build a tiny xsd schema and generate xml files out of that and indeed read property files and map those too... well you map them to enums, we map them to `BitSet`s. For example a certain market like USA is a BitSet of 52 states - depending on what states we need to do different things - we apply a mask... it's somehow complicated to explain in a comment though .

Comment: @Naman the advice is great, but the OP might be in my shoes too - we have no data store for _this part of the app_ - and really don't want to introduce one

Comment: As @Eugene mentioned I cannot introduce a datastore here.

Comment: @Eugene is it possible to paste some sample code etc? or point me to some links where I can figure out how to do this? It is not a constraint for me that these need to be mapped to ENUMS. But I need to know a good approach to do this even if it means using some other solution instead of ENUMs.

Comment: @GhostCat right. reading files/generating XLS is rather boring to be honest and pretty trivial too. The real beauty is to create an API for users to use (in our case) - underneath there are a lot of BitSets and a lot of xor/shift/etc - on the surface callers have a very transparent API. I wish I had the right to post some code, took over 1 year to develop and I simply love it at this point in time

Comment: could you give some insight about why not going into a database usage?

Comment: @Eugene Done. Who I am I to not follow the advise of an experienced user like you ... but I think you should answer, too. You might not show any code, but explaining the basic idea should work, too!

Comment: The code examples are irritating. Why maintaining a `stringValue` that is identical to the `name()` property? Why passing three `MarketplaceID` constants to the `MarketplaceMerchantMapping` constructor, when they are always the same? Besides, using `enum` is not so bad; as long as `Marketplace` is just a two-letter country code, you can add them all, whether being an actual or potential market place for you, and it will rarely need adaptions.

Comment: @Holger the code samples are just code sample i mimic the actual code because I cannot post the actual code. I was trying to communicate the problem and give an idea of the problem i'm facing.

Comment: Sure, but the way you use it determines how the code actually should look like. If these enum constants do not add any worth to the encapsulated string and are even supposed to be extendable, what actual advantage do the offer over just using string constants containing the two-letter codes?

Comment: @Eugene Point noted about the practicality, but yeah there are ways to deal with it - enum, auto-generated code, configuration files, data store to back it up and maybe others. They all might just be a matter of practice given a clear definition of the problem and the solutions still might vary in perspective.

Answer (score 5):

When using a database isn't possible, then a **well maintained** XLS sheet might be the next best option. Together with a well tested process of fetching the sheet data, to either generate code from it, or to be used as some kind of property configuration input.

As the OP figured himself: Java source code isn't ideal when such a large number of "key" properties need to be maintained, but more importantly, are subject to regular updates.

Of course, the **key** aspect here is: *well maintained*. There needs to be a well defined process everybody has to follow, and the whole "chain", from making changes to the XLS (ideally in a version controlled manner), to producing the artefacts required at build time should be simple and well tested.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into this. But I was wondering if there any better way to this. If not this could be the best approach.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik That very much depends. A nicely designed sheet, be it MS office, or Libre, or whatever ... I think that "business" people, responsible for updating such business related information ... something tells me that a business person will prefer a visual tool. Ideally with some macros that prevent misuse, but also easy sorting and such things. YAML ... to a business person is like Java code: gibberish they dont want to look at. And worse: you dont want a person who doesnt understand the file layout have edit in a text editor!

Comment: @GhostCat do we work together and I don't know that? *responsible for updating such business related information...* _exactly_ the reason why not yaml for us

Comment: @Eugene You know, great minds think along. But honestly: that is a common sense thing. I have seen what happens when people are "enabled" to edit text files that somehow change system behavior. And it wasn't always a good experience ....

Comment: @GhostCat really thank you for detailed comments. It's really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Enums must be "known" at compile time. So as long as you work with Enums (and I understand that you would like to work with them because of type safety, IDE support and so forth) 
you have to write them and this is indeed tedious if there are a lot of them with inter-connections.

Now what you're asking for (if I understand you right) is:

- I would like to define a configuration file (json/yaml) whatever
- Based on this file I need to create "something" to work with at runtime.

I suggest here a rather non-widespread approach (at least in my experience) but this is something that will definitely help to get the work done:

**Idea 1**: if its tedious, why not to automate it?

**Idea 2** if you like to work with enums, why not to create enums?

So basically I suggest code generation (and generating enums is simple, because they don't have any actual logic to be done) in build time.

So you'll need to do a couple of things if you decide to follow this path:

- Make sure that the code generation is done before the compilation of the actual classes, otherwise you won't be able to use the auto-generated code from within your classes.
- Make sure that the code is generated properly. Now in the past it was pretty painful process, but now there is a nice little library called [Java Poet](https://github.com/square/javapoet) that makes the code generation a pretty easy process.
- Make sure that this approach integrates will with your build tools. For example, if you use maven, consider creating a maven plugin that will trigger the code generation process and save it in `target/generated-sources`. Then attach it to `generated-sources` phase (that obviously runs before `compile` phase) and the generated sources will be indistinguishable from the point of view of java compiler when it starts to compile your classes.

In order to give you an example I can refer you to something that I've done recently as a pet project for a pretty similar issue (I appologize if it sounds like a self-advertisement, I never "promote myself" in SO, I'm doing this because I really believe that technically this can help if you decide to follow this path, because technically it contains all the pieces glued together):

So my goal was to automate exception creation (which is arguably slightly more complicated than enums generation), just like you, I thought it would be a good idea to create some configuration yaml file, throw into it information about exceptions (traceIds, messages, params, etc.) and let the build process create the actual java code of exceptions.

The source code is available on Github in a project called [Simplex](https://github.com/MarkBramnik/simplex) (simple exceptions handling library). It has maven plugin for the reference, generator that uses Java Poet, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Looking into this.

Comment: +1 for suggesting code generation. I would also add the code-generation part as a sub-module, so that you can version it and pull it from other projects independently, and so that those projects do not have to worry about using outdated versions (yay versioning) or dealing with code-generation plumbing.

Comment: BTW, thank you for sharing the example code. Makes it so much easier to understand what you are saying.

Comment: @SunilKumar, sure, you're welcome, let me know if you have any questions regarding this - I'll try to do my best to monitor this thread...

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to write the enums in a more readable way, you could add an attribute to them:

```
public enum Marketplace {
     US("US", false, true),
     JP("JP", true, false),
     UK("UK", false, true),
     IN("IN", true, false),
     NZ("NZ", true, false),
     CA("CA", false, true),
     FR("FR", false, false);

     // This could go uptp some 400 marketplaces

     private final String stringValue;

     /** Markers for the getters */
     private final boolean isWest, isEast;

     Marketplace(String stringValue, boolean isEast, boolean isWest) {
         this.stringValue = stringValue;
         this.isEast = isEast;
         this.isWest = isWest;
     }

     public boolean isWest() {
         return isWest;
     }

     public boolean isEast() {
         return isEast;
     }
}
```

Technically, you can easily save them in the database, if you make it a property of the enum. If you don't have a datastore available, you will have to maintain them in source code.

Comment: Not really helpful, but I also wonder why someone would downvote it ...

Comment: This isn't what I was looking for. But I'm not sure why did someone downvote this. But Thank you.

Comment: I downvoted this because it didn't answer the question